# XNA 2D Camera, zoom into player

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, camera, matrix

My 2D camera follows the character fine without any zooming. However, when I tried adding a zoom feature using the Matrix.CreateScale(), the camera no longer follows the character properly.

```
public class Camera
{
    private Matrix transform;

    public Matrix Transform
    {
        get { return transform; }
        set { value = transform; }
    }

    public Viewport view;
    public  Vector2 center;
    float zoom;
    float rotation;
    public float Zoom{
        get{return zoom;}
        set { value = zoom; }
    }

    public Camera(Viewport newView)
    {
        view = newView;
        zoom = 2;
        rotation = 0;
    }

    public void Update(Vector2 position, int xOffset, int yOffset)
    {

        if (position.X < view.Width / 2)
            center.X = view.Width / 2;
        else if (position.X > xOffset - (view.Width / 2))
            center.X = xOffset - (view.Width / 2);
        else center.X = position.X;


        if (position.Y < view.Height / 2)
            center.Y = view.Height / 2;
        else if (position.Y > yOffset - (view.Height / 2))
            center.Y = yOffset - (view.Height / 2);
        else center.Y = position.Y;




        transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(
            new Vector3(-center.X + (view.Width / 2), -center.Y + (view.Height / 2), 0)) * 
            Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom, Zoom, 1.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(-center.X + (view.Width / 2), -center.Y + (view.Height / 2), 0); 





    }
}
```

The camera is updated with:

```
camera.Update(character.Position, map.Width, map.Height);
```

With the width and height of the tilemap and the characters current position.
If I change the zoom factor how do i keep the player still in the center w/ the camera following?

Comment: You shouldn't create duplicate questions. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203343/xna-2d-camera-zoom-not-following-character-sprite). If you don't get an answer in one stackexchange site, you should delete it before asking the exact same thing on a different stackexchange site!

Comment: @Joe I've asked the SO mods to merge that here if possible.

Answer (score 2):

From just a quick glance it looks like your matrix is incorrect.  ISROT (identity, scale, rotate, orbit, translation) is the order you should apply your operations.  Your applying translation twice for some reason.

```
transform =
    Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom, Zoom, 1.0f)
    * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation)
    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(-center.X + (view.Width / 2),
                               -center.Y + (view.Height / 2),
                               0);
```